# Issues with Android Studio 1.0.2

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

Did a new install of Android Studio 1.0.2. Getting the following error when opening existing android project for kickflip.io android example (https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-android-example):

```
Failed to create parent directory 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-  2.2.1\daemon' when creating directory 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.2.1\daemon\2.2.1'
```

my user variables are set as follows:

```
ADB C:\Android SDK\platform-tools\
ANDROID_HOME C:\Android SDK\
GRADLE_HOME C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.2.1
MAVEN_HOME C:\Program Files\maven\
PATH C:\Android SDK\tools\,C:\Android SDK\platform-tools\
```

settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'io.kickflip:sdk:1.1.1'
}
```

ADS opens now to a new error:

```
Cause: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling
```

Comment: Did you try to run ADS as an administrator?

Comment: Is this spaces on error message `...\gradle\gradle-  2.2.1\...` a typo or did you inform it like that ? Between gradle and 2.2.1

Comment: @JorgeCampos no spacing errors. I am now getting this error: Cause: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling